# Awk pattern matching on rows that have a value at specific column. No delimiter

Tags: awk

I would like to search a file, using awk, to output rows that have a value commencing at a specific column number. e.g.

I looking for 979719 starting at column number 10:

```
moobaaraa**979719**
moobaaraa123456
moo**979719**123456
moobaaraa**979719**
moobaaraa123456
```

As you can see, there are no delimiters. It is a raw data text file. I would like to output rows 1 and 4. Not row 3 which does contain the pattern but not at the desired column number.

Comment: This have to be done with `awk` or is any approach welcome?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/979719$/' file

moobaaraa979719
moobaaraa979719
```

Comment: Big Apple! Easy-peasy!

Answer (score 0):

An simple `sed` approach.

```
$ cat file
moobaaraa979719
moobaaraa123456
moo979719123456
moobaaraa979719
moobaaraa123456
```

Just search for a pattern, that end's up with `979719` and print the line:

```
$ sed -n '/^.*979719$/p' file
moobaaraa979719
moobaaraa979719
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
awk 'length($1) == 9' FS="979719" raw-text-file
```

This code sets 979719 as the field separator, and checks whether the first field has a length of 9 characters. Then prints the line (as default action).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'substr($0,10,6) == 979719' file
```

You can drop the `,6` if you want to search from the 10th char to the end of each line.